# What is the difference between CentOS-7-live-GNOME and CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD?

Tags: operating-system, centos7

what type of CentOS & should I Install to study and practice Linux security? What is the difference between CentOS-7-live-GNOME-x86_64.iso and CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-2009.iso?

Comment: CentOS-7-live-GNOME-x86_64.iso is the live DVD with Gnome only. Size ~1GB. ... CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-2009.iso is a DVD with packages. Size ~4.4GB. ... ... CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-2009.iso : Size ~9.5GB. .... And the CentOS-7-x86_64-NetInstall-2009.iso, 575MB can install selected . ... Ref. http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/centos/7.9.2009/isos/x86_64/

Comment: which one is the best to install?

Comment: The most easy to handle is the "CentOS-7-x86_64-NetInstall" : Small size, and it's your decision what's going to be installed.